# paypal subscription buttons are not showing on phones

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, paypal, sdk, cross-browser

I'm using Paypal at 4 different places in the app 3 subscriptions and one single payment.

everything works on a desktop, but subscription buttons are not showing on mobiles.

I feel that the problem is in importing the library, is anything wrong with this import?

no errors of any kind, I checked and found PayPal is loaded on phone, but buttons don't show.

```
 <script
src=`https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?clientid=${process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID}
&currency=GBP&disable-funding=credit,card&vault=true&intent=subscription`
></script>
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to check your CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the problem was that buttons are being removed because the `paypalButton.close()` is being called when the state render (don't exactly know why).

please see this issue for more info about the problem:

https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout-components/issues/1506

solved by sleeping 1 second before rendering, I don't know why, but this has solved the problem.

so my code is:

sleep function:

```js
 function sleep(ms) {
     return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }
```

paypa; button component:

```js
 const paypalRef = useRef();
 
// options
 const btnOptions = {
    createSubscription: function (data, actions) {
      return actions.subscription.create({
        plan_id: planID,
      });
    },
    onApprove: function (data, actions) {
      alert(data.subscriptionID);
    },
  };

 // effect, make sure to listen to Paypal library load
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        await sleep(1000)  // sleep second before rendering. <---------------------- solution here;
      if (paypalRef.current) {
        btn = window.paypal.Buttons(btnOptions);
        btn.render(paypalRef.current);
      }
    })();
  }, [window.paypal]);


  return <div className={styles.paypal_btn} ref={paypalRef}></div>;
```